# Switching Languages with resource files on Actionlink click without refreshing the page Contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I am working on an asp.net website which has multi language functionality. Currently my code works with the language switch and it displays the form contents with the language that is selected but if user decides to switch language after filling the form partially, my code refreshes the page and the form data is lost in the process.

I have tried to set the changed language using cookie.

Language Controller code -

```
public ActionResult Change(String Language)
        {
            if(Language != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Language);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Language);
            }

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
            cookie.Value = Language;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Index view -

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", "Change", "Language", new { Language = "en"}, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Françe", "Change", "Language", new { Language = "fr" }, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("spanish", "Change", "Language", new { Language = "es"}, null)</li>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
            if(cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to switch the language and the page contents without refreshing the page ?

Comment: Please refer http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/ site.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's really helpful and i got to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is client side translation. Which means the translation resources have to be present on the page when you change the language.
You can do that with some custom javascript [not the recommended way].

This leads to the question where will resources come from? For example if you have some content like "My project in English" how will the system know what to translate to?

One way is to have the browser translate it on the fly. e.g with google translate. [Here is a way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963066/javascript-jquery-call-google-translate-on-button-click-with-flags).